# Event Handler for Launcpad Header Back Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I need to overwrite the event of Launchpad Header Back Button in certain cases. I tried lots of things like:

```js
try {
 sap.ui.getCore().byId("backBtn").attachPress(this, function(oEvent)  {
  oEvent.preventDefault();
 }.bind(this));
} catch (err) {
 console.log(err);
}
```

or

```js
$('body').mousedown(function(e) {


  var oTarget = $(e.target);


  console.log(oTarget[0].offsetParent.id);
  console.log(oTarget[0]);
  if (oTarget[0].offsetParent.id === "backBtn") {
    console.log("prevent");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }

}.bind(this));
```

In these codes I just tried to prevent the navi, getting back. Didn't work. I want to navigate to certain views in certain cases. For example:

if user is in view 3 -> click Launchpad Back Button -> navigate to view 1 (not the previous navigation target)

But I couldn't stop navigation mechanism to go back to previous target.

I'd appreciate any help or ideas.

Comment: Most answers suggest `setBackNavigation` which is, however, **not** a public API and can be removed with any future SAPUI5 upgrade. Reach out to SAP and submit a new enhancement request as per the note 2469897.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had trouble preventing the default Fiori shell(launchpad) actions in the past myself. A different approach might be to use sap.ui.core.routing's [HashChanger](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger/overview) and/or the [Router](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Router) (presumably you are already using a router in your app).

It's not incredibly elegant, but you could use the HashChanger's `hashChanged` event to determine if your conditions are met (i.e. when old hash = view 3's pattern) you could fire a `Router.navTo("view1sRouteName")`. You could also instantiate a [History](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.routing.History) `sap.ui.core.routing` object to get for certain whether the direction is forward or backward using `History.getDirection()`.

Make sure you read the APIs on the History and HashChanger's dependencies so that you are instantiating at the right time.

Answer (score 6):

First you need to register the ShellUIService in your manifest.json

In manifest.json under sap.ui5:

```
...
"sap.ui5": {
     ...
     "services": {
        "ShellUIService": {
            "factoryName": "sap.ushell.ui5service.ShellUIService"
        }
    }
    ...
}
...
```

then you can override the default behavior in your controller (or from the component)

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getService("ShellUIService").then(function(oShellService) {
    oShellService.setBackNavigation(function() {
        //either do nothing to disable it, or add your own back nav logic
    })
```

})

Comment: Kyle - this is a nice solution. Is there a way to restore the default BackNavigation action? Or do you just set it to something like `window.history.go(-1)` when you need default behavior?

Comment: @MatthewCReddy good question, I'm not sure. using history like you suggested is how i would do it. If i discover anything else i'll let you know.

Comment: According to the documentation, this is the way to go. During runtime, the service oShellService is found and has member setBackNavigation but the passed function is never called.

Comment: @AntonSack "According to the documentation [...]" could you share the documentation? I'm not able to find `setBackNavigation` anywhere in any documentation. It doesn't seem to be a public API.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get it to work reliably with the most voted answer.

This might be against better advice in the documentation, but is working for me:

```
...
    "sap/ushell/ui5service/ShellUIService"
], function (BaseController, JSONModel, formatter, IconPool, ShellUIService) {
...
onInit: function () {
    this.oShellUIService = new ShellUIService({
                    scopeObject: this.getOwnerComponent(),
                    scopeType: "component"
                });
        this.oShellUIService.setBackNavigation(this._navBack.bind(this));

...
```